# The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process

Tags: reactjs, docker, memory, terraform, bitbucket-pipelines

Getting failed while running bitbucket-pipelines.yml in bitbucket building react application docker build

Script:-

```yml
image: hashicorp/terraform
 
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step:
        size: 2x
        name: Build and Deploy 
        image: node:18
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - while true; do echo "Memory usage in bytes:" && cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes; sleep 2; done &
          - while true; do date && ps aux && echo "" && sleep 2; done &
          # Build the Docker image
          - docker build -t xyz:latest .
```

i have increased the size: 2x still faceing same error!! inside the script

Comment: What is the purpose of those `while true; ...` seems that will be an infinite loop

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes it's  a type of loop i am using it to check the memory usage

Comment: @N1ngu The problem I am facing is when I am running the bitbucket pipeline it starts to build the docker images this is the error  "The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process" I am creating image of react application

Comment: With the information you have provided I doubt anyone will be able to reproduce your issue.